# jQuery Mobile Listview in Dialog won't initialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am dynamically creating a dialog that contains a listview and appending it to `body` when the user navigates to a specific `data-role=page`.  After appending the dialog to `body` I call

```
$('#myDialog').dialog();
$('#myList', '#myDialog').listview();
```

When I call the `listview()` function I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery19105852627926506102' of undefined
```

The only way I have been able to initialize my listview is to do it during the `pageshow` event of the dialog, but then the user actually sees the listview items without styling until the `listview()` function is complete.

Is there any way I can initialize a listview inside a dialog before the dialog has been shown?

**Update:**
I get the same error if I use `$('#myDialog').trigger('create').

Comment: Is the `#myList` *inside* the `#myDialog` HTML?

Comment: `$('#myDialog #myList').listview();` this way. In your code you're calling `.listview()` on both dialog and listview.

Comment: @MackieeE - `#myList` is inside `#myDialog`.

Comment: @Omar - `$('#myList', '#myDialog')` should be a selector for `'#myList'` in the context of (inside of) `'#myDialog'`

Comment: @Omar - I've seen some other posts you have responded to on SO and I have a question...  Is it not possible to call the `.listview()` method on a listview that is not on the currently active page?  I didn't see that anywhere in the jQuery Mobile docs.

Comment: Since you're creating a brand new dialog dynamically, you dont need to call any enhancement. just append it to body and `$.mobiel.changePage("#mydialog". { role: "dialog });`.

Comment: here's how to create a dialog on the fly. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/F5r6v/ this is in case you're using jQM 1.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs are treated the same way pages are. When appending a page/dialog dynamically into DOM, you dont need to call any kind of *enhancement*, as they get initialized, as well as all widgets within, prior to showing them.

All you need is to append dialog to `<body>` or `$.mobile.pageContainer` and then open the dialog using `$.mobile.changePage()`.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.append("dialog HTML markup");
$.mobile.changePage("#dialog_ID");
```

Note that calling *enhancement* methods on elements within a page that isn't created/initialized yet, will result an error. However, you can *refresh* widgets on visited/initialized pages.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/F5r6v/)**